# Remove leading 0 and alphanumeric value from string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have values in column i.e A1234, B0045, P0123
I need to remove characters and leading 0 from the string.

I tried couple of things, I have created a function to handle this and in the function I am using regex.

```
PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strText)
```

I want the results to be store the column as below

```
A1234 -> 1234
B0045 -> 45 
P0123 -> 123
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern is wrong.
Try this:

```
DECLARE @strText VARCHAR(20) = 'B0045';
SELECT SUBSTRING(@strText, PATINDEX('%[1-9]%', @strText), LEN(@strText)) AS result
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=017f5c2e50f98bc13e4631e1978aea33).
If you want to update the column:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET col = SUBSTRING(col, PATINDEX('%[1-9]%', col), LEN(col))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another Way:

```
DECLARE @strText VARCHAR(20) = 'ABC0045';
SELECT STUFF(@strText,1,PATINDEX('%[1-9]%', @strText)-1,'')
```